# error C2296: '*' : illegal, left operand has type 'int *'

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to make a function that multiplies 2 matrices into a new one , its almost finished but I am having had a hard time trying to figure out whats wrong with this line

Here's the Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define ROWS_1  3
#define ROWS_2  3
#define COLS_1  3
#define COLS_2  2


int* matrixMultiply(int mat1[ROWS_1][COLS_1],int mat2[ROWS_2][COLS_2])
{
    int mul = (ROWS_1)*(COLS_2);
    int* ArrofRows;
    int sum=0,i,j,k;
    ***ArrofRows = (int*)malloc(mul)*sizeof(int);***
    if (COLS_1 != ROWS_2)
    {
        printf("ERROR!! Operation Failed!Exiting...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        for( i=0 ; i<ROWS_1 ; i++)
        {
            for( j=0 ; j<COLS_2 ; j++)
            {
                for( k=0 ; k<COLS_1 ; k++)
                {
                    sum += (mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j]);
                }
                ArrofRows[(i*ROWS_1)+j] = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int mat1[ROWS_1][COLS_1] = {{2,6,9},{3,5,4},{6,7,8}};
    int mat2[ROWS_2][COLS_2] = {{2,4},{6,1},{4,8}};
    int* NewMat;
    NewMat = matrixMultiply(mat1,mat2);
}
```

Comment: BTW `matrixMultiply` must return a value(int*)

Comment: I *strongly* advise against highlighting specific lines in a c-program with `*`s. Use a comment (either `/* comment until */` or `//comment until end of line`.

Comment: This isn't the cause of the error in question (Sourav Ghosh's answer covers that already), but main must be declared as either `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char**)`.  Some compilers accept `void main()`, but they aren't required to.

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
 ArrofRows = (int*)malloc(mul)*sizeof(int);
```

should rather be

```
ArrofRows = malloc(mul *sizeof(int));
```

or, for better,

```
ArrofRows = malloc(mul *sizeof(*ArrofRows));
```

as, you want to allocate memory for `mul` number of times of the size given by `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(*ArrofRows)`.

Otherwise, as it is currently written, you're trying to multiply a pointer (return value of `malloc()`), which is invalid.

FWIW, to quote the property of multiplication operator (`*`), from `C11`, chapter §6.5.5,

> Each of the operands shall have arithmetic type. [..]

and a pointer is **not** an arithmetic type. Hence the error.

That said, always check for the success of `malloc()` by checking the returned value against NULL before using the returned pointer.

Also, please see [why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Finally, I understand that this code might be just a snippet but in that case also, your `matrixMultiply()` function should be returning a value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i made it eventually, problem was i didnt put a whole () around the malloc parameters.